# How to open a text file as administrator in Pop OS 20.04?

Tags: administration

I have just installed Pop OS 20.04. Previously I used Ubuntu 18. I need to open a text file in root directory as administrator. In Ubuntu I could do it by installing nautilus-admin, then after right click to a file "Open as administrator" option appeared. How can I do it in Pop OS 20.04?

Comment: Can you install `nautilus-admin`?

Comment: Don't fear the command-line! It is your friend (try `sudo nano /root/file` if not used to CLI editors such as Vi). Opening things with elevated priviledges with GUI is usually more complicated than it needs to be, and can lead to problems if you do it wrong.

Comment: Yes I can install nautilus-admin, but after installing the option for open as administrator doesn't show up like in Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't have any problem with command line, but still I wanted o know if there was a way available to do this in GUI.